# How much shorter are your hands than mine?

Tags: questions, syntactic-analysis, comparatives

or **How much more expensive is your phone than mine?**
Are those questions well-formed? 
Do i have to use **much** here?

Comment: **are** is plural.  **phone** is singular.

Comment: But otherwise? Are those questions correct? Can i say "how more expensive is your phone than mine?"

Comment: Yes, you can. *How much faster is your car than mine?* or *How much faster than mine is your car?*

Comment: Yes, they're fine.

Comment: It has to be "how **much** more expensive is your phone than mine?"

Comment: Fine, though in practice most native speakers would say that hands are smaller.  Fingers would be shorter.

Comment: @jamesqf , thanks for this explanation.

Comment: Are you short-handed?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot give chapter and verse on this answer.  I learned my grammar from Latin.  Latin has something called *ablative of (**degree of) ** comparison*.

> Manus meae **multo** breviores sunt quand tuae.  My hands are **much** shorter than yours.

Multo is the ablative of the adjective *multus*.  So literally, it means *...shorter by much*.  English has similar devices.

> My phone is more expensive than yours **by far**
>
> My phone is cooler than yours **by a mile**

These 2 are adverbial phrases and postmodifiers.  *Much* is a premodifier.  *By a mile* and *by far* can become premodifiers with a little modification.

> My phone is **miles** (or **far**) more expensive.

You questions ask **how much** shorter or more expensive.  So this usage can be called ‘degree of comparison.

Health warning⚠️:  The Latin is correct, but I have so far not found evidence for the English.